# Look for standard Java auxiliary class or interface which hold datetime constants

Tags: java, date, datetime

There are many definitions of constants like:

```
public static final long MS_IN_YEAR = 1000L * 3600L * 365L;
public static final int SEC_IN_DAY = 3600;
```

Are there any standard class, which already hold these constants?

Recently I found bug in own constant definition. I like to avoid such bugs at all...

**UPDATE** Also I think that standard definitions provide consistent short names for constants so you shouldn't invent own!

Comment: "Recently I found bug in own constant definition" you mean like the SEC_IN_DAY value ;-)

Comment: `MS_IN_YEAR` is not a constant. Leap seconds aside, you have leap years, which have quite a few seconds more than normal years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there's nothing like this in the standard JDK classes. There are, however, similar fields in the [`DateTimeConstants`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html) class of [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/).

There's definitely [`SECONDS_PER_DAY`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#SECONDS_PER_DAY), but there doesn't seem to be one specifically for millis in a year. You could just multiply [`MILLIS_PER_DAY`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#MILLIS_PER_DAY) by `365`.

Comment: 365 is only right 3 out of 4 years.  also, some years have leap seconds added.

Comment: @DwB That may or may not be relevant to the OP. This answer simply addresses the direct question that was asked.